# Relating Items to one another in MySQL... bit more complicated than face value

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database, relation

## Problem

Basically I want to store and find related items in MySQL, using the below example as reference.

- Relate Item 2 to Item 1
- Relate Item 3 to Item 2
- Relate Item N+1 to Item N...

Now since Item 3 is related to Item 2, and Item 2 to Item 1, Item 3 is related to Item 1 via daisy chain relation.

An example use case would be for relating products to one another, there are 20000 products, and any of those products can be related with any other product.

I have thought of 2 solutions.

## Solution 1

```
Relate Item 2 to Item 1
    - Row 1: Item 2 - Item 1
Related Item 3 to Item 2
    - Row 1: Item 2 - Item 1
    - Row 2: Item 3 - Item 2
```

### Benefits:

1 Relation per Item, minimal rows.

### Cons

If an Item is ever deleted it will break the chain of relations, I can work around this by skipping over deleted Items and keeping the relation intact.

The query will be heavy as it will need to jump through each chain (Row) to build the relation list.

## Solution 2

```
Relate Item 2 to Item 1
    - Row 1: Item 2 - Item 1
    - Row 2: Item 1 - Item 2

Related Item 3 to Item 2
    - Row 1: Item 2 - Item 1
    - Row 2: Item 1 - Item 2
    - Row 3: Item 3 - Item 2
    - Row 4: Item 2 - Item 3
    - Row 5: Item 1 - Item 3
    - Row 6: Item 3 - Item 1
```

### Benefits:

Simple query to get the list of related items as there is a row entry for interrelated items.

### Cons:

Building the relations in the first place takes a lot of management and processing to insert these rows, and the amount of rows inserted can quickly expand with many items.

## Closing

Is there any other solution other than the above two which has the best of both? I am leaning towards the fact that there isn't any other solution other than the two proposed and I will have to compromise, hopefully someone can prove me wrong!

Comment: Are you familiar with graph data structures and graph databases? The problem you describe seems to me to led itself well to a graph style solution rather than just a relational database. You could also maintain some records in the relational database while keep the daisy chain in a nosql graph style database. You'll need to be careful keeping the two data structures in sync.

Comment: What you're looking for is called the transitive closure of a join. `WITH RECURSIVE` queries can do it, but MySQL doesn't support them.  Solution 2 might be a better option in this case, but look into using triggers to maintain related associations in the event of a change.  You could also consider generating the 2nd table from the 1st periodically.